# Merge an entity, change its id, merge again, cause "mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed" error

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have a JPA program where EclipseLink is the Persistence provider. When I merge an user entity, change its ID, and try to merge the same user instance again, an error is thrown. I rewrite my code to illustrate my problem in the simplest way.

```
User user = userManager.find(1);
userManager.merge(user);
System.out.println("User is managed? "+userManager.contains(user);
user.setId(2);
userManager.merge(user);
```

The above code is not in a transaction context. userManager is a stateless session bean with an EntityManager injected.  When executed, the console prints:

```
User is managed? false

Exception [EclipseLink-7251] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [demo.model.User] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

The exception occurs at the second merge() invocation.

If I create a new user, sets its ID and merge it, it works:

```
User user = userManager.find(1);
userManager.merge(user);
System.out.println("User is managed? "+userManager.contains(user);
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setId(2);
userManager.merge(newUser);
```

So what is the difference between the first scenario and second one? According to the JPA specification, as long as the entity is in detached state, the merge should succeed, right?
(Assuming the entity with ID=2 exists)

Why the EclipseLink provider seems to be bothered by the fact that the user entity has been merged before?

Update: It seems to be an bug of EclipseLink. I have replaced the persistence provider from EclipseLink to Hibernate:

I change

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

to

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

No error has been thrown.

Comment: Is your ID a generated value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an bug of EclipseLink. I have changed the persistence provider from EclipseLink to Hibernate:

from

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

to

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

No error has been thrown.

The version of EclipseLink is 2.3.2. (which is shipped with the latest Glassfish application server 3.1.2).

The version of hibernate is, as of now the latest, 4.1.7.

Comment: Still occurs with version 2.6.3

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the `Id` may be inserted/defined - as you do in your second example, but not changed/updated - as you try in your first example. The  JPA provider tries to reflect the change in the database and fails.

JPA 2 spec §2.4 says

> The application must not change the value of the primary key. The
>   behavior is undefined if this occurs.

Comment: But the entity is already detached. When you change the Id of a detached entity, the change won't be reflected in the database.

Comment: @MingtaoSun yes, if the entity isn't managed, the error should occur on the `merge` call, not on the `setId`. Where does it occur? A strange thing is that the entity returned by the EM is said to be not managed. The EM can only return objects contained in the corresponding presistence context and thus only managed ones. If the error happens at `setId`, try detaching the entity explicitly by calling `detach` or `clear` on the EM.

Comment: The error did happen on merge() instead of setId(). According to the JPA spec, when the entity is detached, it can be merged().

Comment: @MingtaoSun - then I was mistaken and my deliberations incorrect. This does look like a bug. Please post your solution as an answer mentioning the versions of EclipseLink and Hibernate and accept it.

Comment: This might have been removed from the final version of the spec. I cannot find it.

Comment: I can still find the sentence on page 28 of the JSR-317 final release, accessed on 2015.04.15 here: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Answer (score 2):

Try `<property name="eclipselink.weaving.internal" value="false"/>` in persistence.xml as per 
http://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/95-Weaving-Problem-in-EclipseLink.html

Comment: worked with jdk 1.8 with ecliselink 2.6.3 running in a wildfly 10

Answer (score 1):

This answer is 4 years late but anyway.

You can update it by executing regular **update queries** using SQL or **JPQL** or **Criteria API**. I find the last one is the best.

Here is a code example that can do the trick. I have tried it in a similar situation and it works fine with EclipseLink.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<User> cu = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(User.class);
Root<User> c = cu.from(User.class);
cu.set(User_.id, newId).where(    cb.equal(c.get(User_.id), oldId)    );
em.createQuery(cu).executeUpdate();
```

Instead of *User_.id* you can pass the name of the field as a String e.g. *"id"*.

Another example http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/